# mongoDB collection.findOne() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have a function in a file that I'm using to get users, the console.log() in the function works, but when using it from another file it returns undefined.

```js
    const db = client.db('TestDatabase');
    const collection = db.collection('users');

    exports.getUser = function(_id) {
        collection.findOne({
            _id: _id
        }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            //console.log(data); // Logs the proper data.
            return data; // Return data?
        });
    }
```

File im using it from:

```js
const database = require('./db.js');

let user = database.getUser(_id);
console.log(user); // This logs "undefined"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP tries to use the function as async, but it must be qualified that way and must return a promise...

```
exports.getUser = async function(_id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    collection.findOne({_id: _id}, (err, data) => {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(data)
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving the collection name ;

```
db.getCollection("<COLLECTION_NAME").find({})....
```

Comment: Should have mentioned that I already used the collection name

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspicious of the use of a callback *and* `await`. There's no need for the callback function in `getUser()` if you're going to change how you handle the response later.

In the case that you're trying to use, I would recommend getting rid of the callback and simply wrapping your calls to `getUser()` in a try/catch so you don't lose your error handling, like so:

```js
function findOne(query) {
   return Promise.resolve(query)
}

function getUser(_id) {
   return findOne({ _id })
}

async function main() {
   try {
      let user = await getUser( 'myId' )
      console.log(user)
   } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
   }
}

main()
```

The other option is to pass a callback into your `getUser()` function, and pass that along in your call to `findOne()` instead of defining it there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make getUser return a promise if you want to call it using `await`. Returning a value from your callback function doesn't return anything to the caller.

These days, `findOne` returns a promise when you don't pass a callback. So you can simply do something like this.

```
exports.getUser = function(_id) {
    return collection.findOne({
        _id
    });
}
```